# Windows 10 loses network connection

Tags: windows-10, network-adapter

PC running win 10 for several years now, no issues.

realtek pcie gbe family controller.

driver version was oct 3, 2017.

Connected via Ethernet cable to router .. router to cable modem.

Today was working online and with PDFs when suddenly lost internet connection.

After a reboot.. "no internet access".

Checked physical cable . it's  a newer cable and intact. connection to router is there .. light on router is green .. trying to connect to router using admin page I've used before .... timed out.

Not even getting near internet ... for some reason my PC/network card no longer can see the router ??

I tried upgrading driver .  it's now on aug 15 2023 .. same issue.
tried several reset options .. nothing seems to work?

I downloaded the realtek diagnostic tool .. went through it .  everything passes .  apparently nothing wrong with network card.

The only possible oddity that may have led to this .. was i was using an older version of pdf creator (v0.9.5) to merge pdf files when things suddenly went screwy. at one point it complained about a dll .. but i can't recall which one exactly.  i decided to uninstall pdf creator and rebooted.

I'm not eager to reinstall windows if there's a solution to this .. hoping for ideas on how to fix/recover?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, just an update .. ironically, it seemed to "fix itself" .. however, I think it's related to some things, so just posting here to complete the story.

Note, I'm still doing troubleshooting, so this isn't a final answer, but it is a resolution to the original post/question.  If I come up with more questions, I'll post another question.

After doing the initial troubleshooting mentioned in original post, and finally logging off the night, and turning PC off.  In the morning, my wife mentioned she had noticed some odd network behavior as well (after I logged off).  So thinking it might be related to the change in our iTalkBB IP phone box (got a new one, the last one died), I promptly unplugged that for the moment, and started my PC up in the morning.

It immediately came up .. with network .. and started printing some pages related to the PDF creator merging activities I was doing night before when this all started.
I purged the print queue, restarted the printer, and rechecked everything on my pc ..  "all good".

So issue was definitely nothing specific to the PC, other than 1 or both of the following:

1. PDF creator v0.9.5 - causing some kind of issue with network (ie spamming printer driver or something? is that possible it causes interference with network?)
   and/or
2. italkBB - something wrong with the box ?

When I have time, I'm going to do some more controlled testing/experimentationg with this new iTalkBB box to see if is having any affect (the previous box never had any issues in the years we had it ... but the power supply died, so we got a new box from them ... will have to check if the new box is messed up).

The final piece to this ... When my PC booted up, everything was fine, except for Discord. It came back with "your account is blocked ... we detected some suspicious activity originating from ... etc"

So I went into troubleshooting Discord, and long story short: went into the router admin page, got into Connection Status, and released/renewed my IP from the ISP .. (got the same IP .. )
but that activity seems to have cleared "something" .. and after one more reboot of my PC .. everything back to normal.

---

TLDR: after booting up in morning, and unplugging new iTalkBB ip phone box, purging print queue of some rogue prints related to PDF Creator and then renewing IP from ISP, everything started working fine.